# In spite of socket-pouch connection being established, sync is not functioning

Tags: couchdb, angular5, pouchdb

The project in question is using 11 PouchDBs. To ensure syncing, all 11 DBs were instantiated (with sync) when the Angular 5 application was loaded/bootstrapped. Since sync did not function (due to the limitations set by browsers) we moved towards socket-pouch as a solution. We disabled sync on all DBs and incorporated socket-pouch sync to only one DB. The socketPouchServer runs on localhost:5000 & the CouchDB is hosted on DigitalOcean.

On running the system,
the following logs are observed in the browser. As you can see, an "aborting" error is being logged.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26055473/38247973-8eef489a-3764-11e8-8411-6b5b20436d19.png

the code for the same is

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchDBFind from 'pouchdb-find';
import SocketPouchClient from 'socket-pouch/client';

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);
PouchDB.adapter('socket', SocketPouchClient);
PouchDB.debug.enable('pouchdb:socket:*');

this.dailyMovementDB = new 
PouchDB(`${username}_${environment.REQUIRED_DB_VERSION_NUMBER}_daily-movement`, { auto_compaction: true });
    this.dailyMovementDBRemote = new PouchDB(
    {
        adapter: 'socket',
        name: `${username}_${environment.REQUIRED_DB_VERSION_NUMBER}_daily-movement`,
        url: `${environment.REMOTE_COUCH_DB_BASE_URL}`
    });

    var syncHandler = this.dailyMovementDB.replicate.to(this.dailyMovementDBRemote
    ).on('change', function (change) {
        // yo, something changed!
        console.log('yo, something changed', change);
        instance.autosaveMessageService.syncingProcessEndedSubject.next(false);
    }).on('paused', function (info) {
        console.log('replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection', info);
        // replication was paused, usually because of a lost connection
        instance.autosaveMessageService.syncingProcessEndedSubject.next(true);
    }).on('active', function (info) {
        // replication was resumed
        console.log('replication was resumed', info);
        instance.autosaveMessageService.syncingProcessStartedSubject.next();
    }).on('denied', function (info) {
        // handle complete
        console.log('denied', info);
        instance.autosaveMessageService.syncingProcessEndedSubject.next(false);
    }).on('complete', function (info) {
        // handle complete
        console.log('handle complete', info);
        instance.autosaveMessageService.syncingProcessEndedSubject.next(false);
    }).on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        // instance.createDailyMovementPouchDBs(username);
        // totally unhandled error (shouldn't happen)
    });
```

And the following logs appear on localhost:5000 (socketPouchServer)
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26055473/38248011-ac49b9ca-3764-11e8-8501-74576c8c1e1f.png

the following is the code for the socketPouchServer

```
var socketPouchServer = require('socket-pouch/server');

const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

socketPouchServer.listen(5000, {
remoteUrl: 'http://remoteurl:5984',
}, () => {
console.log('Hi');
});


Please guide how to resolve this issue.
```

Comment: I'm curious, when you declare `new PouchDB`, what is the value of URL you are using as `${environment.REMOTE_COUCH_DB_BASE_URL}`?

Comment: @user3405291 REMOTE_COUCH_DB_BASE_URL: 'http://159.xx.xxx.190:5984'

Comment: Why is the `${environment.REMOTE_COUCH_DB_BASE_URL}` pointing to your digital ocean droplet and NOT to your `socketPouchServer`?

Comment: My mistake. The value of REMOTE_COUCH_DB_BASE_URL: '159.xx.xxx.190:5984'; was from another branch and is not the value used in the code in question. In the code in question, the value of REMOTE_COUCH_DB_BASE_URL is infact the socketPouchServer url which is 'ws://localhost:5000'. Again, apologies for the error in the comment.

Comment: In the code for the socketPouchServer, the `remoteUrl` is set to `'http://remoteurl:5984'`. It is pointing to DigitalOcean droplet, right?

Comment: Yes, It is pointing to DigitalOcean droplet